# Снижение производительности из-за многократного вызова String.hashCode()

Tags: java, производительность

Ищу причины проблемы производительности в Desktop-приложении. YourKit показал, что при изучаемом действие 20% времени тратится на метод `hashCode()` (вызывается 2 миллиона раз).

```
public class ClassName {
  private String id;

  public ClassName(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Посмотрел реализацию метода `hashCode` у `String`:

```
public int hashCode() {
int h = hash;
    int len = count;
if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
    int off = offset;
    char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Получается, что он проходится по каждой букве, т.е. работает за O(len). Сначала думал возвращать в качестве hashCode длину строки, но посмотрел, что здесь все строки одинаковой длины. При этом этот объект почти везде используется как ключ в `HashMap` (что объясняет количество вызовов). Поэтому так делать не получится. Как бы вы подходили к решению такой проблемы производительности?

Comment: навеяло ответами коллег: а вы какую версию JDK используете?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предполагаю, что вы не до конца проанализировали `report` от профайлера.

Что занимает остальные 80% процессорного времени? Может быть, стандартная хэш-функция ни в коей мере не может быть приближением *идеального равномерного хэширования по Кормену* для вашего случая?

`hashCode()` для `String` написан неглупыми людьми, и о его оптимизациях обычно говорить просто бессмысленно. А вот **поразмыслить над остальной частью кода**, в принципе, стоит.

---

*По поводу возможных вариантов решения:*

- Хэш-функции очень легко поддаются исследованию. Разделите количество ваших объектов на количество уникальных хэшей, и вы получите амортизированное число элементов на один `bucket`. Если оно велико, то классический `O(1)` вполне себе может выродиться в `O(N)`.
- Замените вашу хэш-функцию на длину строки или на ASCII-код первого символа в строке. Как изменятся результаты профайлера? Как изменится степень заполненности `bucket'ов`?
- `hashCode()` у `String`, судя по [этому референсу,](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Performance/) обрубает длинные строки и хэширует только их порцию (правда, почему-то, в вашем коде это не отражено). Возможно, ваши строки начинают различаться в самом конце?
- В конце концов, попробуйте заменить контейнер. Лично у меня в `production'е`, `FastMap` работал намного шустрее `HashMap'a`. Можете попробовать любую реализацию ассоциативного контейнера, который `Tree`-подобен и не требует вычисления хэша. Вдруг для вашего случая `O(lgN)` окажется быстрее, нежели `O(1)` из-за влияния константы. Можете просто отсортировать `ArrayList` и воспользоваться бинарным поиском. **Разумеется, здесь все зависит от задачи и на практике бывает, что асимптотические результаты совершенно не отражают текущей картины.**

Comment: Причина тормозов оказалась действительно не в hashCode :(

Answer (score 1):

Взгляните на String.hashCode() еще раз. hash кэшируется при первом вычислении. Вероятно не там ищите проблему с производительностью.

Comment: Да, я это видел. O(len) - это оценка сверху.

Comment: Пересмотрите алгоритм. 2 млн. вызовов для одного действия - это ненормально.

Answer (score 0):

если проблема именно в лишних вызовах функции hashcode тогда ее можно решить, напр. так:

```
public class ClassName
{
  private String id;

  public ClassName(String id) {
     this (id.hashcode());
  }

  private ClassName(int hashcode) {
     this.hashcode = hashcode;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return this.hashcode;
  }

  ...
}
```

или так:

```
public class  Classname {
private int hashcode = -1;
private String id = null;

...

public int hashcode()
{
    if (-1 == this.hashcode)
    {
        this.hashcode = id.hashcode();
    }
    return this.hashcode;    
}
```

возможно есть смысл использовать какой-то шаблон для создания этих обьектов, вместо стандартного метода использовать какую-то свою реализацию которая позволяет вычислять hashcode для всей строки на основе hashcode ее составных частей (напр. строк длиной по 4 символа). в таком случае у вас за какое-то время работы программы скопится большая часть необходимой информации.

есть еще один вариант: если у вас количество строк (те которые id) ограниченное, напр. - ограниченное длинной 30 символов, возможно есть смысл сгенерировать hashcode для всех потенциально возможных значений, и загружать их при запуске приложения. все остальные генерировать. этот вариант можно скомбинировать с предыдущим. каждый раз когда вы генерите хешкод вы сохраняете его в кеше. при завершении работы приложения кеш сбрасывается на диск. при запуске считывается итд.